# How to insert excel dynamic columns names to sql using C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I want to insert excel data to sql, but excel column names are changing frequently.

Below is the code I have written for excel bulk upload

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""", path);
        //// Create Connection to Excel Workbook
        {
            string destablename1 = string.Empty;
            destablename1 = "[admin.AttendanceData]";

            DataTable Data = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Attendance$]", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(Data);
                conn.Close();
            }

            var dacObj = new DAC();
            String strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Emp ID", "Citrix_ID");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Full Name", "Full_Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Band", "Band");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Cigna DOJ", "Cigna_DOJ");
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destablename1;
                dacObj.OpenConnection();
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Data);
                dacObj.CloseConnection();
            }
        }n
```

how to add dynamic column names from excel to sql?

sample picture of excel sheet data

[image]

Here after Cigna DOJ columns will change for every month.

Comment: I would use SQL DataAdapter to put results into a DataTable.  You can the get the column names out of the table.  The other choice is to use the getschema method oledb to extract the tables names and column names which is harder.  You can search the web for the format of "getschema oledb excel.".

Comment: How does your sql table admin.AttendanceData look like? Do you upload the monthly data to the same table? if yes, do you add extra 30 columns each month? if you are not doing any data processing in your code, why not using SQL data importer?

Comment: Yes I will add extra 30 columns every month but every month these columns will change, it has to replace exisiting column names